# Add many folders on same project with PhpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I use `Sublime Text` and I want to switch on `PhpStorm`. I want to add several folders on same project in `PhpStorm` like `Sublime Text`.

Comment: well you can add as many folders as u want . what exactly is your problem ?

Comment: Are you trying to say that you wish to view multiple projects?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the **Add Content Root** in `Settings` | `Directories`:

[image: add content root]

Comment: aw... simple drag and drop did not cut it :P